# Request for explanation of an idiomatic D2 construct

Tags: d, dmd

I often come accros the following construct that I don't quite grasp in a D2 source code:

```
alias uint SymbolRef;

struct SymbolTable {
  alias entries this;
  SymbolRef startSymbol;
  Symbol[] entries;
}
```

What does imply the `alias entries this;` inside the type definition given that there is already `Symbol[] entries;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Official docs](http://dlang.org/class.html#AliasThis)

In short: **alias this** construct is D's way of multiple implementation inheritance. In your example struct SymbolTable should behave similarly to Symbol[] with addition of few extra stuff. It can be implicitly converted to Symbol[].

However, I have often heard that more complex usage of **alias this** is considered buggy in current compiler implementation, so better be careful here and ready for bug reports ;)

Related chapter of "*The D Programming Language*" is "*6.13 Multiple Subtyping*"